How is this question lacking details or clarity?
The question: Is it reasonable to view religions as theories, and, if so, to examine their theoretical predictions in order to test them empirically?
Two comments supporting the question:

@tkruse It's not like "are rocks animals" because he's right, religions are theories. You're downvoting (presumably) and VTC because you don't agree. Don't do that. Christianity for example makes predictions about what will happen after you die, and if you die and do not observe those predictions, those predictions have been falsified. –
causative


The question is perfectly clear, and should not have been closed. We have 12 answers and counting, and 11 upvotes and counting on one of the answers, so the community here is appreciative of both the question and the answers. – Dcleve

How is the question lacking details or clarity?

Never mind, it got reopened, thanks.
